# How to get 2 images to match and stay revealed using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a memory game for my mini project and am trying to get 2 images to stay revealed if it's a match. However, the images aren't staying revealed although its a match. I'm trying to match the 2 images by their Id, but doesn't look like it's working. Please take a look at my code, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

JS

```
     $('.flip-container').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.flipper').addClass('flip');
    var $flip = $('.flip');

    if ($flip.length === 2) {
      setTimeout(flips, 800);
    }
  });

  function flips() {
    if (matching()) {
      $('.flip').removeClass('flip').addClass('delete');
      $('.delete').bind('.flip');
      console.log('It\'s a match!');
    } else {
      $('.flip').removeClass('flip');
      console.log('No matches');
    }
  }

  function matching() {
    if (flip.length === 2) {
      if (flip[0].attr('id') === $(flip[1].attr('id')) {
        $('.flip').addClass('matchFound');
        $('.flip').removeClass('matchFound');
      }
    }
  }
```

[My GitHub link for this project](https://github.com/TLawesomeness/memory-game)

Comment: not sure what you expect `this` to be inside `matching()` ... is probably `window` and have no idea what `$(this).flip` is. Nothing showing that in your code. Suggest you create a demo

Comment: $(this) is the image you just clicked, refer to my Github, for the whole JS file, its under /clients/main.js

Comment: check it by logging to console, there is nothing to give `this` any context inside `matching()`, thus it would default to `window`. Your Git repo is irrelevant, questions should be self contained and people shouldn't be expected to wade through a repo to find your code